# AdaptiveCard prompt inside a WaterfallDialog keeps showing over and over

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm testing an **Adaptive Card** that only has 2 elements: a text and an action:

[image]

Its definition is this:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is a test",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Option 1",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Option 1",
                    "value": "2"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "Select a option",
            "id": "option"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Next"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

}

I want to show this card as part of a prompt inside a dialog of a **WaterfallDialog**, so I do this:

```
public class MyDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public MyDialog(string id) : base(id)
    {
        //...
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("Test"));
        //...
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> TestStep(WaterfallStepContext stepcontext, CancellationToken cancellationtoken)
    {
        // Loads the card from the JSON I showed above
        var card = await LoadAdaptiveCard("MyCard.json");
        return await stepcontext.PromptAsync("Test", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
            {
                ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                Content = JObject.FromObject(card),
            }),         
            Style = ListStyle.None,
        }, cancellationtoken);
    }
}
```

The prompt shows OK, but after I click on "Next", the card is showed again. It seems like it's stuck on it and never goes to the next dialog step.

I would like the **Next** button to be like a "Submit" button that proceeds to the next step. What's wrong with my code?

### Notice

The real Adaptive Card is this one:
[image]

I posted a simpler one for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I see you're using a choice prompt. Where are the choices?

Comment: The choices are part of the final AdaptiveCard (Input.ChoiceSets). I guess I'm not using it properly. Anyways, I have seen that if I add a validator to the ChoicePrompt and return *true*, it effectively goes to the next step.

Comment: Does that mean your issue has been resolved? Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @KyleDelaney It worked at least! but I still don't know if it's workaround or a legitimate solution :) I'm not very sure about how to proceed 

Comment: @KyleDelaney as someone interested in using adaptive cards as prompts, I appreciate the genius workaround of having a validator always return true, but it would be good to know the proper way to set up cards as prompts so that their values are accepted without having to force it through with a hack.

Comment: @SuperJMN - Well I'd like to answer your question, but I need you to understand that your question as you've asked it still doesn't make sense. You have a choice prompt with no choices, so why would you expect that to work? You say the Adaptive Card is ultimately supposed to contain choices but the one in your minimal example doesn't so I have nothing to work with. I can see that you want the dialog to continue past the prompt, but the whole point of prompts is that they have to return a result. What could the result of a choice prompt be if there are no choices?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I created a simple card for brevity. The real card will be different. Check the OP in a minute. I will upload a snapshot.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I used a Prompt (ChoicePrompt) without choices because I haven't found a better way to make the bot await for user input. That's why I'm asking the question: It doesn't feel good to me, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: @SuperJMN - Yes, I understand that you created a simple card for brevity, but it's a bit too simple. Your minimal example needs to actually reproduce the problem, which it can't do if there are no choices. Can you please edit your question to include the JSON of an Adaptive Card that includes the sort of information you're trying to get from the prompt?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Done! Although the real-life card is generated procedurally. In the following step, I get the selected options using the WaterfallContext.Context.Activity.Value, that is a JObject with the data from the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain situations, a choice input can be used to automatically recognize a choice from card action data. You can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive/Input/InputDialog.cs#L535) how the incoming activity's value is also used as input instead of just the activity's text.

> ```cs
> if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dc.Context.Activity.Text) && dc.Context.Activity.Value != null)
> {
>     input = dc.Context.Activity.Value;
> }
> ```

However, you're not using a choice input, you're using a choice *prompt*. Of course, there's nothing wrong with that. Prompts are exactly what you should be using since you're using a waterfall dialog and not an adaptive dialog. It's just important to keep in mind that prompts are somewhat simpler than inputs, and in most cases they'll only account for the incoming activity's text and not the value.

That explains why your prompt isn't recognizing the card's action data, but there's a bigger problem to consider. It doesn't matter whether you're using a prompt or an input because they're both wrong in this case. Choice prompts/inputs are only meant to recognize one singular choice, so they could potentially work for the minimal sample card you've provided, but they can't possibly work for the actual card you want to use. Your actual card has multiple choice sets, and there's no way for a choice prompt or a choice input to account for multiple choices made at the same time.

Given that choice prompts aren't the right choice for you, you still need to know what to do instead. You say you want to continue on to the next waterfall step, and that's easy. In order to continue to the next waterfall step instead of repeating the prompt, don't even use a prompt. Just send the Adaptive Card on its own as a normal activity and then return an end-of-turn result. If the user enters text instead of clicking the button, you'll have to handle that somehow in the next waterfall step.

Supposing that's not quite satisfactory and you actually want to do more than just make sure the waterfall dialog continues, you may still need some kind of prompt. Prompts make sure the dialog doesn't continue until you get the information you need, and in your case you want the information from the Adaptive Card. There are a few options for you:

1. Make your own special Adaptive Card prompt
2. [Use an Adaptive Card prompt someone else has made](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Prompts/AdaptiveCardPrompt.cs)
3. Use a text prompt

That third option may sound strange, but text prompts are useful because they'll accept any string by default, and as with any prompt you can supply your own custom validator to make sure the data is in the format you want. I've given more information about this in the "Adaptive Cards in Dialogs" section of my blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/